# I have created a Windows Service and I want to open a seperate app, p.e. notepad.exe, when I start the service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service

The app notepad.exe appears to start in the background, if I go to the task manager it's there, but I can't open it and use it.

`Process.Start("notepad.exe")`

This code works if I run it on other apps, but for some reason when I run this code on a service the app doesn't open the same way.

I also tried to start a batch file that opens the notepad, but it does the same thing.

Comment: It’s because its running on the system user... Not your user.

Comment: Based on my research, I suggest that you can look at [Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows Vista and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/winsdk/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later) to try to make it.